# Eigenvalues and Eigenvectors of diagonal marix

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Problem:

> Let $D$:= diag($\lambda_1, \ldots, \lambda_n$), i.e., $D$  is a diagonal matrix  in $\mathbb{C}^{n\times n}$ with entries $\lambda_1, \ldots, \lambda_n$ ∈ $\mathbb{C}$ on its diagonal.
>
> Find $\sigma$($D$) and all eigenvectors of $D$.

My thoughts:

As the spectrum of $D$  is the set of all eigenvalues, then $\sigma$($D$) should be just $\lambda_1 \cdots \lambda_n$ = $\mathbb {\lambda_n}^{n}$ .

But how can I find the eigenvectors ? I know I have to calculate the $D$ - $\lambda I$.

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 4):

If the matrix is diagonal, the eigenvectors are just the standard basis of $\mathbb{C}$:

$$
e_1 = (1, 0, \dots, 0)^t, \dots, e_n=(0,\dots, 0, 1)^t \ .
$$